# HttpUtility.UrlEncode standard encoding vs specified encoding?

Tags: c#, .net, urlencode

What would the difference be between:

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncode("some string with é and β and stuff")
HttpUtility.UrlEncode("some string with é and β and stuff", Encoding.UTF8)
HttpUtility.UrlEncode( "some string with é and β and stuff", Encoding.Default )
```

result being:

```
some+string+with+%c3%a9+and+%ce%b2+and+stuff
some+string+with+%c3%a9+and+%ce%b2+and+stuff
some+string+with+%e9+and+%df+and+stuff
```

When testing, I get the same result for the first two, so can i safely assume that UTF8 is the default unless specified, or can that differ on different systems?

I have seene examples of unicode escape sequences that looks like this:

%u00e9 (é)

Fairly certain that paypal sends that in their IPN-requests. Why doesn't .NET encode like that?

Comment: The HttpUtility.UrlEncode method uses UTF-8 encoding by default. Therefore, using the UrlEncode method provides the same results as using the UrlEncode method and specifying UTF8 as the second parameter. http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/4fkewx0t(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The source code for the method `HttpUtility.UrlEncode Method (String)` from the Reflector:

```
public static string UrlEncode(string str)
{
    if (str == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    return UrlEncode(str, Encoding.UTF8);
}
```

To your question:

> so can i safely assume that UTF8 is the default unless specified

Yes, you can.

Comment: You also asked "or can that differ on different systems?" - Mono uses the same UTF8. But Microsoft should **have** stated in MSDN what encoding is assumed by default. Everyone may think the default is Encoding.Default

Comment: Alright, very thorough answer, thank you. Yes, Encoding.Default really implies that it would be, "default".

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can safely assume that UTF8 is the default based on your examples above.  Keeping in mind that the default encoding with .NET is determined by the underlying code page of the operating system.

The '%u00e9' example that you have seen from PayPal is actually a [non-standard implementation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Non-standard_implementations) for encoding Unicode characters.  According to Wikipedia, this implementation has been rejected by the W3C.

Comment: Actually, it wasn't paypal who sent it. Seems like ASP.NET converts it to the non-standard implementation in it's Request.Form Collection. raw data: &address_street=%C3%A5lderstigen, Request.Form data = &address_street=%u00e5lderstigen, DOH!